# In Rails, how do I figure out if an array of objects contains specific attributes matching given values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, model, attributes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.0.1 with Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of objects, stored in the array, "results."  Each object has a numeric attribute

```
numeric_attr
```

I would like to know, given my array, how I can tell if I have exactly one object with a numeric attribute value of "1" and incrementing by one.  Order is not important.  So, for instance, if I have an array of three objects,

```
[MyObject(numeric_attr = 2), MyObject(numeric_attr = 1), MyObject(numeric_attr = 3)]
```

I want to know if I have exactly one object with numeric_attr = 1, another object with numeric_attr = 2, and another with numeric_attr = 3.  So the above satisfies the condition.  The below example does not

```
[MyObject(numeric_attr = 4), MyObject(numeric_attr = 1), MyObject(numeric_attr = 3)]
```

because although there is an object with numeric_attr = 1, there is no object with numeric_attr = 2.  It is possible thet the numeric_attr field is nil.  How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This one-liner should work:**

```
results.map(&:numeric_attr).sort == (1..results.count).to_a
```

**Explanation:**

```
results
#=> [#<MyObject:... @attr=2>, #<MyObject:... @attr=3>, #<MyObject:... @attr=1>]

results.map(&:attr)
#=> [2, 3, 1]

results.map(&:attr).sort
#=> [1, 2, 3]

(1..results.length).to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3]

# therefore:
results.map(&:attr).sort == (1..results.count).to_a
#=> true
```

**If there is a chance that `numeric_attr` is `nil`:**

```
results.map(&:attr).compact.sort == (1..results.count).to_a
```

Of course, if there is even a single `nil` value, the result is guaranteed to be `false`.

**If the sequence could start at any number, not just 1:**

```
results.map(&:attr).sort == results.count.times.to_a.
  map { |i| i + results.map(&:attr).sort.first }
```

This is not very efficient though, as it sorts the numbers twice.

Comment: Nice. What do you think about something like: `((1..results.count).to_a-results.map(&:numeric_attr)).empty?`

Comment: I like that too. Even shorter: `!(results.map(&:numeric_attr)-(1..results.size).to_a).any?`

Comment: Shorter still: `!(results.map(&:attr)-a=*(1..results.size)).any?`

Comment: This gives me a syntax error (Ruby 2.3.3). This, however, doesn't: `!(results.map(&:attr)-(a=*(1..results.size))).any?`

Comment: But then the extra parens make it the same length as your shorter version. So, you win, I lose!!! You d'man.

Comment: You came up with the one with the subtraction in the first place, so let's call it even :)

Comment: Hi, I was trying "results.map(&:numeric_attr).sort == (1..results.count).to_a", but if "numeric_attr" is nil, this fails with a "comparison of Integer with nil failed" error.

Comment: Perhaps the `numeric_attr` attribute of one of the objects is `nil`?

Comment: THat's my suspicion as well.  Is tehre any way to adjust your one-liner to take into account nils?

Comment: @Dave Alternative solution added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If they always start at 1 @Máté's solution works, if they can start at any arbitrary number then you could:

```
count = 0
array_objects.sort_by(&:numeric_attr).each_cons(2) {|a,b| count+=1 if a.numeric_attr==b.numeric_attr-1 }
count+1==array_objects.count
```

Not as elegant but handles a lot more situations